# Reads clause using Frama-C and WP-Plugin

Tags: c, static-analysis, frama-c

When defining an axiom for string length, I need to use the reads clause.

```
/*@
predicate Length_of_str_is{L}(char *s, integer n) =
 (0 <= n) && \valid(s+(0..n)) && s[n] == 0 &&
 \forall integer i; 0 <= i < n ==> s[i] != 0;

axiomatic LengthAxiomatic{
    logic integer Length{L}(char *s) reads s[..];
    axiom str_length{L}:
    \forall integer n, char *s; Length_of_str_is(s, n) ==> Length(s) == n;
}
@*/
```

However, the reads clause of an arbitrary area is not yet implemented in WP, what other alternatives are there?

I need this axiom in order to prove some functions from string.h (eg: strcmp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Oxygen version of Frama-C/Wp, it is safe (although incorrect from ACSL point of view)
to use `reads *s` instead of `reads s[..]` in such a situation.

The next incoming release of Frama-C will enable general read clauses.

Comment: That seems to be working, but isn't `read *s` the same as `reads s[0]`?